# Google OAuth Popup continues without switching back to Return URL after successful External Login in Web Application asp.net 4.5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-oauth, asp.net-identity

Google OAuth Popup continues without switching back to Return URL after successful External Login in Web Application asp.net 4.5

The code:

```
javascript for click event:

<script type = "text/javascript">
#google-signin-button{
document.getElementById("google-signin-button").addEventListener("click", getAccessToken);
}​


html code for Google OAuth Button:

<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<div id="g_id_onload"
 data-client_id="MyClientid"
 data-context="signin"
 data-ux_mode="popup"
 data-login_uri="https://localhost:XXXXX/login.aspx"
 data-auto_select="true"
 data-itp_support="true">
</div>
<div class="g_id_signin" id="google-signin-button"
<script src="https://gridnow.net/GoogleAuthentication.js" defer></script> 
 data-type="standard"
 data-shape="rectangular"
 data-theme="outline"
 data-text="signin_with"
 data-size="large"
 data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>

Expected the control to return ReturnUrl from popup
```

GoogleAuthentication.js code is as follows:

```
function getAccessToken() {
if (location.hash) {
    if (location.hash.split('access_token=')) {
        var accessToken = location.hash.split('access_token=')[1].split('&')[0];
        if (accessToken) {
            isUserRegistered(accessToken);
        }
    }
}
}

function isUserRegistered(accessToken) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Account/UserInfo',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/JSON',
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.HasRegistered) {
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
            localStorage.setItem('userName', response.Email);
            window.location.href = "Data.html";
        }
        else {
            signupExternalUser(accessToken);
        }
    }
});
}

function signupExternalUser(accessToken) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Account/RegisterExternal',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    },
    success: function () {
        window.location.href =
```

"/api/Account/ExternalLoginprovider=Google&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a61358%2fLogin.aspx&state=GerGr5JlYx4t_KpsK57GFSxVueteyBunu02xJTak5m01";
}
});

```
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask]  edit your question describe what you are doing include enough code to reproduce the issue.  You have only included JavaScript code here yet you state you are using C# .net we need a full [example].

Comment: GoogleAuthentication.js code is as follow:s:

function getAccessToken() {
    if (location.hash) {
        if (location.hash.split('access_token=')) {
            var accessToken = location.hash.split('access_token=')[1].split('&')[0];
            if (accessToken) {
                isUserRegistered(accessToken);
            }
        }
    }
}